# Nothing executed after for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, cgi

I'm running the following code to (ultimately) create a video from a series of jpegs, the jpegs are in a file structure like this: /year/month/day/hour/minute.jpg, I have a small python script to move each file from an entire day (in chronological order) to another file in the format 0000.jpg, 0001.jpg, etc. This works wonderfully, but nothing after the for loops will execute (for example, "HELLO" won't print out. What is wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, time, shutil
print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
os.chdir("../")

def comp(x, y):
    return int(x) - int(y)

def comp2(x, y):
    return int(x[:-4]) - int(y[:-4])

cwd=os.getcwd()
srcdir=cwd + "/cams/droid/archive/images/" + time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
hours=os.listdir(srcdir)
hours=sorted(hours, cmp=comp)
destdir=cwd + "/cgi-bin/images"
index=0

for folder in hours:
    minutes=os.listdir(srcdir + "/" + folder)
    minutes.remove("anim.gif")
    minutes=sorted(minutes, cmp=comp2)
    for files in minutes:
        cpS='%s/%s/%s'%(srcdir, folder, files)
        cpD='%s/%04d.jpg'%(destdir, index)
        shutil.copyfile(cpS, cpD)
        index+=1

print("HELLO")
```

Comment: I don't program in Python, but when debugging loops it's good to see what's going on. If you can, output some data to a file (or the screen?) within the inner loop, right after `index+=1`.  I'd output dpS and cpD if I were you.  See if they show what you expect, and end where you expect.

Comment: Are you sure the loop is not hanging on one of it's tasks?  A rough type of debugging you could try is to add statements that print the two values 'folder' and 'files' in the inner for-loop and then some statement at the end of that inner for-loop to make sure it gets through everything.

Comment: Another thought - if `shutil.copyfile(cpS, cpD)` can't find a file, does it throw an error?  Or just stop?  If it just stops, the last file in the loop might be missing, but it would appear to you that the programm just stopped without printing("HELLO").

Comment: Haha - @JonathanV and I came up with the same ideas!

Comment: @BrettFromLA I was just finishing to proof read my post when I saw someone else beat me to it!

Comment: hmmm... i told it to `print(folder)` before the second for loop, and it never gets to the last hour for some reason, let me see if I can figure that out

Comment: currently facepalming myself, the last hour directory didn't have an "anim.gif" file, so it threw an error... @BrettFromLA your "rough" debugging methods saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

The final directory didn't contain an `anim.gif` file, so the last iteration threw an exception and the program silently broke.